# How to have the Wi-Fi monitoring mode in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, broadcom

I have **Dell Inspiron 3542** laptop, with the '***Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n***' wireless chipset.

When I'm trying with

```
sudo iwconfig wlp6s0 mode monitor
```

to have monitoring mode, it shows

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlp6s0 ; Operation not supported.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Monitor mode is not supported for this adapter in linux.

Comment: thanks, but there is no solution, or having USB adapter is better ??

Comment: To get monitor mode you need to get another PCI or USB adapter.

Comment: sorry, but what about this {Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device XXXXX ; Device or resource busy.}